# subgroup of General Linear Group

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

I'm looking for method to define a subgroup of General Linear group, similar to Special Linear Group.
The special linear group $\text{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ is the group of $n \times n$ matrix with determinant 1.
And I want to define another group that is also the group of $n \times n$, but with non-negative determinant.
I am wondering if there is an existing definition ?

thanks you!

Comment: How do you propose to define the inverse of a matrix with determinant zero? It seems like it would be better to consider the group of $n\times n$ matrices with positive determinant.

Comment: An existing *name*, or definition? Because what you've said (with the fix @charmichael561 points out) is a fine way to define things.

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb{R})/ \{\pm 1\}$ and $SL_n(\mathbb{R})/ \{\pm 1\}= PSL_n(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: The group of matrices with positive determinant is sometimes denoted $GL_n^{+}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think probably positive determinant is the right thing to consider.